# How to verify PDF signature from command line the way adobe reader verifies them?

Tags: pdf, command-line-interface, signature, adobe-reader

I would like to programmatically verify whether a signed PDF document will show up in Adobe Reader as

- the signature being valid
- the signature embedding a signed timestamp
- the signature being LTV enabled

Does Adobe reader provide some command line interface with which this could be checked, if not, how could this be verified programmatically?

Comment: Do you really want to use a program whose command line arguments remain obscure and require a high level of permissions at the proprietor's website?

Comment: Do I WANT? no. What I NEED: a programmatical way to determine whether Adobe Reader will show the signature as valid, LTV enabled and timestamped

Comment: *"whether a signed PDF document will show up in Adobe Reader as ..."* - You are aware that the validation results of Adobe Reader depend on its specific configuration? What shows valid on your Adobe Reader, does not necessarily show as valid on mine and vice versa.

Comment: Furthermore, which signatures are considered invalid due to allowed/disallowed changes after signing, is a moving target.

Comment: Yes, there are definitely paid options at least. However: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask This question should be asked here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/